# Force javadoc to ignore an annotation

Tags: annotations, javadoc

I'm trying to document an annotated interface and include a sample of how it's used in the javadoc. e.g.

```
/**
 * Here's an example usage:
 *
 * <PRE>
 * @IFaceAnnotation(value="")
 * public interface IFace {
 *
 *     @MethodAnnotation("")
 *     public String Method();
 * }
 * </PRE>
 */
```

However, Javadoc treats my annotations as javadoc instructions (like @param etc.) and as a result only prints:

> Here's an example usage:

In the generated documentation. The only way i've been able to stop this is by adding an extra char before the annotation e.g.

```
/**
 * Here's an example usage:
 *
 * <PRE>
 * \@IFaceAnnotation(value="")
 * public interface IFace {
 *
 *     \@MethodAnnotation("")
 *     public String Method();
 * }
 * </PRE>
 */
```

but this looks a bit messy.

Just wondered if anyone had any suggestions, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'&#064;'` instead of the @, but thats even more ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `{@literal @}`. No nasty escape characters.

```
/**
 * Here's an example usage:
 *
 * <PRE>
 * {@literal @}IFaceAnnotation(value="")
 * public interface IFace {
 *
 *     {@literal @}MethodAnnotation("")
 *     public String Method();
 * }
 * </PRE>
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in the {@code} notation?

Comment: That alone doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the correct and complete answer is:

```
/**
 * Here's an example usage:
 *
 * <pre>
 * {@code}
 * &#064;IFaceAnnotation(value="")
 * public interface IFace {
 *
 *     &#064;MethodAnnotation("")
 *     public String Method();
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

which results in

[image]